# Moonlight sonata, note lengths inside triplets

Tags: piano, practice, beethoven

[image]

The first triplet is very uneven. Its total length is 1/4.

Triplet 1:

A (1/8), D#(1/4), F#(1/4 divided by 3 = 1/12)

For how long should I hold A and D#? Should I hold D# with 1st finger until C# from the 2nd triplet is pressed with the 2nd finger?

[image]

Or just together with F#:

[image]

Triplet 2:

C# (1/4), F#(1/12), A(1/12)

Here I keep pressing C# with 2nd finger while playing F# (4th), A (5th)

Triplet 3 (simple):

I hold B# till the end of this triplet and the next one.

Please, explain, how to play the 1st triplet?

Comment: Up - and down- stems **always** indicate different voices.  Each voice here is clearly marked as to note lengths, as Lawrence "KIng of" Payne answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see WHEN the D# and C# are played.  There are no rests in the lower voice, and no overlaps.  All you're really being asked to do is 'bring out' the melody A, D#, C#.    Maybe easier to see if I write it separately, with the triplet indications that Beethoven has tired of writing by this point.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it doesn't matter how long you hold those notes, because Beethoven tells you to keep the damper pedal held down *for the entire first movement.*  Even though a modern Steinway sustains longer than his piano, some respected pianists still perform it like this.